# Why is pointerdown event delivered to a wrong PIXI.Container after scaling containers up and down? Test case attached

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have a custom class called `Tile` extending [PIXI.Container](https://pixijs.download/v5.3.3/docs/PIXI.Container.html).

It is instantiated three times and stored in the variables: `r`, `g` and `b`.

First I drag the 3 tiles around, horizontally (i.e. keeping the tiles in the 4th row):

[image: screenshot 1]

And after some time, when I click the **middle** tile, then wrongly the `onDragStart` method of the **left** tile is called (in the screenshot below you can see that I have clicked the blue tile, but the green has been raised):

[image: screenshot 3]

So the `pointerdown` event is called on the wrong object!

I have a feeling that the root cause for this is that the `Tile` objects are scaled up when clicked and thus Pixi.js thinks that it should deliver the event to the still big object.

But I haven't been able to come up with a fix or a workaround yet.

Below is the complete and simple test case for my issue.

The bug is always reproducible for me, just move the tiles around 5-10 times and you will be able to see it.

```js
function Tile(color, onDragStart, onDragMove, onDragEnd, x, y) {
    PIXI.Container.call(this);

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.interactive = true;
    this.buttonMode = true;
    this.on('pointerdown', onDragStart)
        .on('pointermove', onDragMove)
        .on('pointerup', onDragEnd)
        .on('pointerupoutside', onDragEnd);

    this.graph = new PIXI.Graphics();
    this.graph.beginFill(color);
    this.graph.drawRect(0, 0, Tile.W, Tile.W);
    this.graph.endFill();
    this.addChild(this.graph);
    this.cacheAsBitmap = true;
}

Tile.W = 100;
Tile.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Container.prototype);
Tile.prototype.constructor = Tile;

Tile.prototype.startDragging = function() {
    this.scale.x = 1.6;
    this.scale.y = 1.6;
    this.alpha = 0.8;
};

Tile.prototype.stopDragging = function() {
    this.scale.x = 1;
    this.scale.y = 1;
    this.alpha = 1;
    // align x, y to the checker board grid
    this.x = Tile.W * Math.floor((this.x + Tile.W / 2) / Tile.W);
    this.y = Tile.W * Math.floor((this.y + Tile.W / 2) / Tile.W);
};

var app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: Tile.W * 8,
    height: Tile.W * 8,
    view: document.getElementById('pixiCanvas'),
    backgroundColor: 0xFFFFFF
});

var background = new PIXI.Graphics();
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
            background.beginFill(0xCCCCFF);
            background.drawRect(i * Tile.W, j * Tile.W, Tile.W, Tile.W);
            background.endFill();
        }
    }
}
app.stage.addChild(background);

var r = new Tile(0xFF0000, onDragStart, onDragMove, onDragEnd, 3 * Tile.W, 3 * Tile.W);
var g = new Tile(0x00FF00, onDragStart, onDragMove, onDragEnd, 4 * Tile.W, 3 * Tile.W);
var b = new Tile(0x0000FF, onDragStart, onDragMove, onDragEnd, 5 * Tile.W, 3 * Tile.W);

app.stage.addChild(r);
app.stage.addChild(g);
app.stage.addChild(b);

function onDragStart(ev) {
    this.data = ev.data;
    var pos = this.data.getLocalPosition(this.parent);
    this.x = pos.x - this.width / 2;
    this.y = pos.y - this.height / 2;
    // put the tile on top
    app.stage.removeChild(this);
    app.stage.addChild(this);
    this.startDragging();
}

function onDragMove() {
    if (this.data) {
        var pos = this.data.getLocalPosition(this.parent);
        this.x = pos.x - this.width / 2;
        this.y = pos.y - this.height / 2;
    }
}

function onDragEnd() {
    if (this.data) {
        var pos = this.data.getLocalPosition(this.parent);
        this.data = null;
        // the next 2 lines are not needed here, but 
        // in my real game I put the tile beneath the HUD
        app.stage.removeChild(this);
        app.stage.addChildAt(this, app.stage.children.length);
        this.stopDragging();
    }
}
```

```css
#pixiCanvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #CCF;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 4px red dotted;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="pixiCanvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixi.js@5.3.7/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixi.js-legacy@5.3.7/dist/pixi-legacy.min.js"></script>
```

Additionally I have created [issue 7233](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/7233) at Github and you can also see the bug in [my real app](https://wordsbyfarber.com):

[image: app screenshot]

**Things I have tried sofar, which haven't helped:**

- Switching `Tile` base class from `PIXI.Container` to `PIXI.Sprite`
- Moving `startDragging` and `stopDragging` calls before `removeChild` and `addChild(At)`
- Removing `removeChild` and `addChild(At)` calls completely
- Removing `this.scale.x = 1.6` and `this.scale.y = 1.6`
- Searching for [pointerdown](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/search?q=pointerdown) at Pixi.js repo (do not understand the source code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with -

```
this.hitArea = new PIXI.Rectangle(0, 0, Tile.W, Tile.W);
```